# Zend: How does LDML work?

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

Currently I try to fix a issue on our SocialEngine installation (which is built on Zend) which shows in the language selector one language not in its native name (like "Deutsch" for "German") but in the language the user has set the frontend (so instead of "Deutsch" you would see "German" when you set the language to English).

When looking in the source I've seen that Zend_Locale_Data loads a list of languages which are available for the system and tries to read a LDML file from a path which seems not to be on my machine:

```
$temp = self::_getFile($locale, '/ldml/localeDisplayNames/languages/language', 'type');
```

When the path is not on my computer, it has to be in the web but doing a search for "ldml" or "zend ldml" I don't get any hint on this topic. Could you guide me through the fog?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'/ldml/localeDisplayNames/languages/language'` that you see is not a file path but a XPath expression, the file that is read is an XML file located in `Zend/Locale/Data/` and the filename is related to the given `$locale` parameter.

e.g. For the english locale, the XML file loaded should be `Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml`. Opening this file will show you the structure selected by the XPath expression

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ldml>
<!-- content skipped -->
<localeDisplayNames>
    <!-- content skipped -->
    <languages>
        <language type="aa">Afar</language>
        <language type="ab">Abkhazian</language>
        <!-- etc... -->
```

Comment: Aaaah! Yes, that makes more sense than any path in the web or something like that. Huge thanks! *check*